# "Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE" exception with mysql and vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, stored-procedures, datagridview

for a few days I've been trying and trying to get the stored procedure to work in vb.net, but I can't seem to make it work.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out here. I've been trying really hard to solve this problem, but I just can't find a solution.

```vb
Private Sub getID()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim con_str = ""
    Dim con As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(con_str)
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = "getID()"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "113")
    Dim da As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.SelectCommand.Connection = con
    da.Fill(dt)
End Sub
```

When I try to run this I get the exception "Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE otrs.getID; expected 1, got 0" on the line da.Fill(dt). I don't really know why this happens. There is no argument declared in my stored procedure.

My stored procedure should be fine. Calling it out of the dbms worked out fine, but here is the code anyways:

```sql
delimiter $$
CREATE DEFINER=`otrs`@`%` PROCEDURE `getCIs`()
BEGIN
SELECT  
    l.source_key AS base_id,  
    c1.configitem_number AS base_number,
    v.name as base_name,
    l.target_key AS link_id,  
    c2.configitem_number AS link_number,
    v1.name as link_name,
    t.name as link_type
FROM  
    otrs.link_relation AS l
        INNER JOIN  
    otrs.configitem AS c1 
        ON l.source_key = c1.id     
        INNER JOIN  
    otrs.configitem AS c2 
        ON l.target_key = c2.id    
        INNER JOIN
    otrs.link_type AS t
        INNER JOIN
    otrs.configitem_version AS v
        ON l.source_key = v.configitem_id
        INNER JOIN
    otrs.configitem_version AS v1
        ON l.target_key = v1.configitem_id;
END$$
```

And yes, I did use the search-function and I googled quite a lot, but I'm still thankful for any kind of information regarding my problem.

So I found out was wrong. Apparently you dont need the () after the procedure-name. Im not 100% sure though, because now nothing happens at all:

```vb
Private Sub getID()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim con_str = ""
    Dim con As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(con_str)
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Try
        cmd.CommandText = "getID"
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message())
    End Try

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 113)
    cmd.Connection = con
    Dim da As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Try
        da.Fill(dt)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message())
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong it creates a new command with the command text of "call getID()" and adds it to the adapter with no parameters

```
  Dim da As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter = _
   New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter("call getID()", con_str)
```

you want

```
  cmd.CommandText = "getID"  
  Dim da As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter = _
   New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(cmd, con_str)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I did that, but now I get another exception: "Procedure or function '`getID()`' cannot be found in database '`otrs`'." which is weird, because the procedure is definitely in the database. Changed the code just now :)

Comment: After researching a little I found out that this exception is mostly related to lower-case upper-case, but the db-name is lower case in the connection string as well as in the db.

Comment: You need to use just the name `getid` when the command type is `CommandType.StoredProcedure` and not `call getID()`. I updated the question to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

You never actually execute cmd. Also, as you mentioned above, you don't need the parenthesis for the proc call. It should look something like this.

```
MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("getID", con);
DataSet DS = new DataSet();
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
```